# SSIS C# Script Task fails around 250MB memory usage

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, 64-bit

I have an SSIS package that simply runs an SSIS script task written(not by me). This script then dynamically creates packages and runs them, in a threaded fashion, managing the active number of threads. This is launched using SQL Agent. This is grabbing data from an Attunity Source against an 11g Oracle DB.

When I watch the process in the taskmanager I see DTexec.exe slowly consuming more and more memory. when it gets to around 250MB it fails. It often returns different errors every time, sometimes it even shows up as a cancellation request from the SQL agent.

I have decreased max memory to give more to the OS, didn't work.

It shouldn't be a memToLeave issue as it is 64bit. 
I have tried running through the command line, nothing.

Windows Server 2003 
SQL 2008R2

I am having so much trouble with this and have tried everything I could find on the web. Anyone have any ideas? I am sure I left something out here so ask and I will find out for you.

Comment: You have my condolences. I assume the reason for the master package is just something they could squeeze into production easier than giving the DBAs an exe to install? When you say you `run it from the command line, nothing` Does that mean no errors or it doesn't run at all?

Comment: It exhibits the same behavior as running thru the Agent. It slowly fills(RAM) and then dies(250MB) without leaving a SSISlog message and most often no windows event, SQLDumper seems clueless.

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured it out.

The way in which the C# is written does not have a mechanism to explicitly destroy the threads being created, however the reason this was never an issue before is because the script task creates a DLL inside the SSIS package. My environment has the 32 bit runtime by default, and built it as such. If an SSIS package is built in 32bit mode it has a hard RAM limit of 256MB, 64bit has no such limitations. So what did I have to do?

Open the package in Visual Studio ON THE SERVER ITSELF, and then save it. This forces it to recompile in 64bit mode(if it is the default run time on that server).

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you had simply run the package using the 64 bit dtexec, would it have still exhibited the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes. it did exhibit this same behavior, died at 256MB, and since 64 bit isn't the most verbose when it comes to error logging, among the myriad other factors that made this a perfect storm, it was really difficult to trouble shoot.